# SSIS pre and post execute handlers are not firing

Tags: ssis

I added some event handlers to a package with 5 executables. Each of the 5 has OnPostExecute and 1, a sequence container that contains the other 4, has both OnPostExecute and OnPreExecute.

The Sequence Container has an Execute SQL Task on pre execute that inserts and gets @@IDENTITY and the post has an Execute SQL that updates the @@IDENTITY record.

None of the Event handlers seem to be firing. Also, breakpoints set on pre and post executes don't seem to fire.

[image: Control Flow - 5 Executables]

[image: Sequence OnPreExecute Event Handler]

[image: Package Explorer]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post some screenshots. Show your Control Flow, Package Explorer and then a specific Event Handler that you've created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, when you "Execute Container" is VS, it does not fire any defined events. When I run this code from the top, all events fire as intended.

Answer (score 3):

So you'll see in your Control Flow screenshot that you have a Sequence Container named "Copy Table Transaction".

You then have a OnPreExecute Event Handler defined on the Executable named "Copy Table Transaction". However, in the Object Explorer, you have your cursor on the Event Handlers at the Package/Control Flow level. You see that's empty because you haven't defined anything there.

*But* I also see that you have an OnPostExecute event handler defined for "Get ObjectID" inside the Sequence Container. The Sequence Container has both Pre and Post execute Event Handlers.

If you expand the OnPostExecute Event Handler defined on "Copy Table Transaction", you should see Executables named "Expression Task" and "Execute SQL Task"

Comment: I kind of got that while I was adding the pictures. I still don't understand why they are not firing.